# VBA ByRef argument type mismatch even though types match?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a `String()` array, which I am looping through using `For Each`. Inside of this loop, I am running a function that takes the String as an argument. I keep getting ByRef argument type mismatch when calling the function, and I'm not sure why. I can confirm that the variables used are strings:

[image]

though one of them is an empty string, that shouldn't matter. Any ideas?

[image]

```
PeriodArray = f.getPerArray
PreviousPeriodSheet = ""
For Each PeriodSheet In PeriodArray
    Debug.Print PeriodSheet & " " & TypeName(PeriodSheet) & " | " _
              & PreviousPeriodSheet & " " & TypeName(PreviousPeriodSheet)
    
    Call RenderPeriod(PeriodSheet, PreviousPeriodSheet)
    PreviousPeriodSheet = PeriodSheet
Next
```

Here's the parameters for the `RenderPeriod` function

```
Function RenderPeriod(PeriodName As String, PrevPeriodName As String)
```

And here's the f.getPerArray function, which is where the String() array comes from:

```
Function getPerArray() As String()
```

I'm no VBA wiz, but I don't see why it's not accepting my Strings.

Comment: https://www.wallstreetmojo.com/vba-byref-argument-type-mismatch/#:~:text=The%20Excel%20VBA%20error%2C%20%E2%80%9CByRef,one%20macro%2C%20not%20another%20macro.&text=In%20the%20above%20code%20of,variable%20%E2%80%9CA%E2%80%9D%20as%20long.

Comment: Would help to show a complete example, and tell us exactly where the error is.  It's difficult to tell what's going on from these snippets.

Comment: Need also to include the relevant variable declarations...

Comment: @TimWilliams Those are the variable declarations lol. I haven't been explicitly declaring variable types because I assumed VBA could implicitly figure those out upon first use. Seems I may be incorrect there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`PeriodSheet` is either undeclared, or declared as a Variant.  You haven't declared it as `String` or you'd be getting the error "For Each control variable on arrays must be Variant" from the `For Each` line.

So if `PeriodSheet` *needs* to be a Variant you can avoid the type mismatch error when calling the function by doing something like this:

```
RenderPeriod CStr(PeriodName), PreviousPeriodSheet
```

Note `PreviousPeriodSheet` should be declared `As String`

Comment: My confusion is that, since `f.getPerArray` returns a `String()` array, why would `PeriodArray` not be a String array? Does VBA not implicitly inherit types like that?

Comment: And does `PreviousPeriodSheet = ""` not declare it as a string? This is the first time it's used in the program.

Comment: I've added `Dim PeriodArray() As String` and `Dim PreviousPeriodSheet As String`. Now `PreviousPeriodSheet` works fine but `PeriodSheet`, which is the control variable of the `PeriodArray` being looped over, is still throwing the ByRef error.

When I try to add `Dim PeriodSheet As String` before the loop, it throws the "For Each control variable on arrays must be Variant" error. How do I define it's type?

Comment: If you want to use `PeriodSheet` in a `For Each` loop on a String array, it *has* to be a Variant (which is what that error message is telling you)  So declare it `As Variant` and cast it to a String using `CStr()` when you pass it to `RenderPeriod`.

Comment: yup, that worked. I guess I don't really understand why VBA can't infer that `PeriodSheet` is a String from the array's type, nor does it give you an option to type it in the loop declaration, like `For Each PeriodSheet As String In PeriodArray` But your are correct, `CStr()` solved the issue. The more ya learn